# Iterate all over the pixels of the binary image in c# with OpencvSharp

Tags: opencv, image-processing

How can I iterate all over pixels of this binary image[image: this binary image].
I want to skeletonize or thinning this "white" line but still do not know how to iterate all over the pixels

Comment: The OpenCV [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/master/db/da5/tutorial_how_to_scan_images.html) will show you how to iterate over an image, but it will likely be faster (and easier) to use a built-in function to process your image.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not actually know what kind of "skeletonize", "thinning" you mean.

This is a simple way to make it s

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("B0xTI.png")

kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
thinning  = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations = 2)

cv2.imwrite("thinning.jpg",thinning)
```

output image:
[image]